# How to click element in Form using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I try to click element in Form but robot doesn't fond a element that I provide.
I try 3 ways but it still not found locator

```
 Wait Until Element Is Visible  &{FinishCall}[endCall]  timeout=60s
 Click Element   &{FinishCall}[endCall]

 Submit Form   &{FinishCall}[endCall]

 Execute Javascript   document.getElementById("j_id0:currentCallLogForm:currentCallLogPB:j_id7:j_id9").addEventListener('click', function (){console.log('execute on click')});
```

Example HTML the element is under iframe

```
<input class="btn" id="j_id0:currentCallLogForm:currentCallLogPB:j_id7:j_id9" name="j_id0:currentCallLogForm:currentCallLogPB:j_id7:j_id9" onclick=";A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id0:currentCallLogForm',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:currentCallLogForm:currentCallLogPB:j_id7:j_id9','oncomplete':function(request,event,data){goToCustPage();},'parameters':{'j_id0:currentCallLogForm:currentCallLogPB:j_id7:j_id9':'j_id0:currentCallLogForm:currentCallLogPB:j_id7:j_id9'} ,'status':'sfStatus'} );return false;" value="Finish Not On Call" type="button">
```

Anyone please help me.

Comment: have you selected iframe before operating on element

Comment: Thank you it work fine now by select iframe first.

Comment: select iframe first then click form and then click element in form

Comment: @Dev You should post it as an answer or either ask the OP to post the working code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most probably element you operating on is inside the iframe, check iframe on page and select it first -  using following keyword

```
Select Frame    name or id of iframe
Click Element    element locator or name or id
```